# Creating custom user types for jsonb columns in hibernate postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsonb

I am trying to migrate my spring mvc project database from mongodb to postgresql.
Spring version 4.3.8.RELEASE
Hibernate version 5.2.10.Final
Postgresql db version is 9.6

I am trying to implement create, read, update operations for the following entity.

**BeneficiaryData.java**

```
@Document(collection = "beneficiary_data")
public class BeneficiaryData extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private Integer beneficiaryId;

    private Map<Integer, Object> customData;
    private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> customMultipleData;
    private Date lastUpdatedOn;

    public BeneficiaryData() {
    }
}
```

In mongodb this entity was stored as a json document and the conversion from json to object for the fields customData, customMultipleData, rcfData were handled by spring data.

For storing this in postgresql I thought of using the following table structure making use of postgresqls jsonb type.

```
CREATE TABLE ebbin.beneficiary_data
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('bms_v21.beneficiary_data_id_seq'::regclass),
    beneficiary_id integer NOT NULL,
    custom_data jsonb,
    custom_multiple_data jsonb,
    last_updated_on timestamp(3) without time zone,
    CONSTRAINT beneficiary_data2_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

For handling the two jsonb types I implemented two cutom hibernate UserTypes

**JSONBCustomDataUserType.java**

```
public class JSONBCustomDataUserType extends CollectionUserType implements ParameterizedType {

    private static final String JSONB_TYPE = "jsonbCustomData";
    public static final String CLASS = "CLASS";

    @Override
    public Class<Object> returnedClass() {
        return Object.class;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] { Types.JAVA_OBJECT };
    }

    // ... implementations for nullSafeGet, nullSafeSet ...
}
```

and **JSONBCustomMultipleDataUserType.java**

```
public class JSONBCustomMultipleDataUserType extends CollectionUserType implements ParameterizedType {

    private static final String JSONB_TYPE = "jsonbCustomData";
    public static final String CLASS = "CLASS";

    @Override
    public Class<Object> returnedClass() {
        return Object.class;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] { Types.JAVA_OBJECT };
    }

    // ... implementations for nullSafeGet, nullSafeSet ...
}
```

My entity for postgresql is now
**BeneficiaryData.java**

```
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "jsonbCustomData", typeClass = JSONBCustomDataUserType.class, 
             parameters = {@Parameter(name = JSONBCustomDataUserType.CLASS, value = "java.util.Map")}), 
    @TypeDef(name = "jsonbCustomMultipleData", typeClass = JSONBCustomMultipleDataUserType.class, 
             parameters = {@Parameter(name = JSONBCustomMultipleDataUserType.CLASS, value = "java.util.Map")})
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "beneficiary_data")
public class BeneficiaryData extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "beneficiary_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer beneficiaryId;

    @Type(type = "jsonbCustomData")
    @Column(name = "custom_data", nullable = true)
    private Map<Integer, Object> customData;

    @Type(type = "jsonbCustomMultipleData")
    @Column(name = "custom_multiple_data", nullable = true)
    private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> customMultipleData;


    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "last_updated_on", length = 19)
    private Date lastUpdatedOn;

    public BeneficiaryData() {
    }

    // ...
}
```

Also created a custom postgresql dialect so that the new user types can be registered.

**CustomPostgreSqlDialect.java**

```
public class CustomPostgreSqlDialect extends PostgreSQL95Dialect {

    public CustomPostgreSqlDialect() {
        super();
        this.registerColumnType(Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "jsonbCustomData");
        this.registerColumnType(Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "jsonbCustomMultipleData");
    }
}
```

However when I try to save an entity using session.save() I get the following error.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not insert: [com.tcs.bms.persistence.entity.BeneficiaryData];
.
.
.
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unknown type jsonbCustomData.
```

I am guessing this has something to do with me registering column type JAVA_OBJECT to both jsonbCustomData and jsonbCustomMultipleData

I am saying this because when I tried with just the jsonbCustomData user type (after commenting out the customMultipleData field in the entity and removing from the table), I was able to successfully insert, update and fetch data.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little late to the party, but without knowing the exact solution to the problem, I'd have two suggestions:

1. Based on your PSQLException of Unknown type, your dialect might need to look like this:

```
    public class CustomPostgreSqlDialect extends PostgreSQL95Dialect {
        public CustomPostgreSqlDialect() {
            super();
            this.registerColumnType(Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "jsonb");
        }
    }
```

...as the according [javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html#registerColumnType-int-java.lang.String-) states, that the second attribute needs to be '*The database type name*' & PSQL won't know anything about a type named "jsonbCustom.."

2. Don't even write a custom dialect! I don't know the content of your extended `CollectionUserType`, but I got a working project with a pretty similar setup (Spring 4.3.14 / Hibernate 5.2.12 / PSQL 9.5) and all I had to do was creating custom UserTypes & registering/annotate those types to the class & their according fields. If you prefer to I'm happy to share the code.